# Rails.where Greater/Lesser Than without writing SQL statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have DB query

```
ageVariable = 36
Actor.where("age > ?", ageVariable)
```

is that possible to avoid `?` syntax?

I'm looking for `:key` based solution that would look something like this:

`Actor.where(age: greater_than(age_variable)`  or `...where(age: > age_variable)`

#### Edit:

In response to @bounty answer:
Range doesn't solve problem.

`Actor.where(:created_at => (1000000.years.ago..2.days.ago)` sounds terrible

Comment: Yes I did, but I still hope to see some non-arel solution

Comment: o, I see. I thought you simple don't want the sql

Comment: I wasn't aware of arel solution so your answer taught me a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) to get it done without using raw SQL:

```
Actor.where(Actor.arel_table[:age].gt(36)).all
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use range condition for this.

```
ageVariable = (36..1000)
Actor.where(:age => ageVariable)
```

This will give all actor which are in between 36-1001

Comment: That doesn't work for dates.
`Actore.where(:created_at => [1000000.years.ago..2.days.ago]` ?

Comment: My mistake. Range need to be in round() bracket. Edited ans.

Comment: I mean whole idea doesn't work. I don't want to query `BETWEEN`. I want to generate `Greater than` sql

Comment: As per my knowledge, you can't use < > = sign with key in where clause as key is symbol so it need its value which can be given using => .

Answer (score 0):

```
ageVariable = 36
Actor.where("age > :target_age", target_age: ageVariable)
```

I avoided `?` and made it look like the latter one `...where(age: > age_variable)`...And I'm not even using `between` but `greater than`. Did I get closer to what you have in your mind?